# How to access HTML link content using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML page which contains a table for the year 2015. On this HTML page, there are links from 2011 to 2015. Every year has different table. I need to access these table elements using JavaScript. Any ideas about how to do it?

Thanks

Comment: do they have a pattern in their IDs or class attributes? please post some part of it.

Comment: Access = get elements values? Provide HTML and desired output.

Comment: I have this webpage: http://www.uta.fi/sis/tauchi/publications.html with the links. I can get the publication data of 2015. But I don't know how to get the other years. Link changes like this for different years: http://www.uta.fi/sis/tauchi/publications.html?year=2014

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I would parse the entire page. Right click the screen and click view source in windows. This will show the xml of the webpage that you could parse. I would advise you to use jparse.

Comment: Yes you are right. I have parsed the page for the current selection. But the page contains links to other pages that I also need to parse. I don't know how to access those pages using JavaScript.

Comment: Can you see the links in the xml?

Comment: Original link is http://www.uta.fi/sis/tauchi/publications.html when I select the link, it goes to the new link like http://www.uta.fi/sis/tauchi/publications.html?2014 and retrieves new table elements. Links are referred as href elements in the HTML source code.

Comment: When I click on the url it takes me to a different site. No offense of course but maybe you are using the wrong link? Or maybe the url in the xml is wrong? I am assuming the url you want to use is the button labeled url on the webpage.